# Um imóvel pode-se alugar? Ou só arrendar?

Tags: uso-de-palavras

Disseram-me que alugar deve ser usado **só** para móveis, e arrendar **só** para imóveis.
Mas eu sempre ouvi dizer "casa alugada" e "alugar uma casa".

É verdade que os termos são mutuamente exclusivos?

---

No que toca a `arrendar`, é claramente [só para imóveis](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/arrendar).

Acerca de `alugar`, não é tão claro.
Por um lado, parece ser um [sinónimo de arrendar](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/alugar).
Por outro, `aluguer` é [cessão ou aquisição *de um objeto ou serviço* (...)](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/aluguer) - não me parece que "objeto" inclua imóveis.

Comment: Se "aluga-se imóvel" for um erro de português, será o erro com maior número de ocorrência na língua portuguesa!

Comment: Não seria o primeiro erro desse género: por exemplo, [despoletar](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/despoletar).

Comment: O Portuguese.SE está me mostrando como o Português de Portugal é diferente do Português do Brasil! Nunca havia ouvido a palavra "despoletar", nem "aluguer" no Brasil!

Comment: (Em Portugal é mais normal usar-se a palavra despoletar erradamente que corretamente... por exemplo, erradamente assim: "os pais estavam furiosos com o condutor que atropelou a criança, *mas* o bombeiro *despoletou* a situação".)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isto vale para Portugal. [O Artigo 1023 do Código Civil português define este uso](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=W0IbBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT500&lpg=PT500&dq=artigo+1023+codigo+civil+portugal&source=bl&ots=iAx1SHriua&sig=tNN_Vj0XOyo13NnMBvfKoUs9HZE&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAmoVChMI3q3h5IiDxwIVQg6QCh10FgYS#v=onepage&q=artigo%201023%20codigo%20civil%20portugal&f=false), [mas não é um consenso na língua portuguesa como um todo](http://www.dicio.com.br/alugar/). Diz o artigo:

> «a locação diz-se arrendamento quando versa sobre coisa imóvel e aluger quando é sobre coisa móvel.»

No Brasil, [há uma diferença substancial entre arrendamento e aluguel](http://www.gigaconteudo.com/diferenca-entre-aluguel-e-arrendamento) (a palavra no português de Portugal é "aluguer"): o arrendamento possui ao final do contrato a opção de compra. O aluguel não possui essa opção.

Comment: Se tem acesso à página que indicou no link do [Artigo 1023 do C.C.P.](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=W0IbBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT500&lpg=PT500&dq=artigo+1023+codigo+civil+portugal&source=bl&ots=iAx1SHriua&sig=tNN_Vj0XOyo13NnMBvfKoUs9HZE&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAmoVChMI3q3h5IiDxwIVQg6QCh10FgYS#v=onepage&q=artigo%201023%20codigo%20civil%20portugal&f=false) poderá citar o texto relevante? Agradeço :) EDIT: já foi possível o acesso, é referido: «a locação diz-se arrendamento quando versa sobre coisa imóvel e aluger quando é sobre coisa móvel.»

Comment: @Armfoot Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Obrigado! Aliás a frase original é: «A locação diz-se arrendamento quando versa sobre coisa imóvel, aluger quando incide sobre coisa móvel.» (no comentário estava no limite de carateres). É interessante que a maior parte das agências imobiliárias em Portugal usam o termo arrendar. A exceção parece ser o [casa.sapo.pt/Alugar](http://casa.sapo.pt/Alugar/).

Answer (score 3):

Eu sempre ouvi [arrendamento](http://www.gigaconteudo.com/arrendamento-de-imovel-rural) no contexto de propriedade rural. Normalmente uma terra improdutiva, cujo dono não tem o capital necessário para iniciar a produção *arrenda* a terra para que outro lá produza. Normalmente o preço é acordado em função do que vai ser produzido lá, p.ex. tantos Kgs de boi vivo ou sacas de arroz por hectare.

O [aluguel](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/aluguel) é a cessão temporária de um bem móvel ou imóvel em troca de um valor monetário, normalmente pago mensalmente.